# Getters and setters from vb 6 to vb .net

Tags: vb.net

How do I convert the following? I'm porting a vb 6 app to vb .net.

```
Public Property Get Width() As Long
   Width = m_lWidth
End Property
Public Property Let Width(ByVal value As Long)
   m_lWidth = value
End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Long
   Height = m_lHeight
End Property
Public Property Let Height(ByVal value As Long)
   m_lHeight = value
    End Property

Public Property Get PartHeight(Optional ByVal eWidthOptions As THEMESIZE = TS_TRUE) As Long
   Dim tSize As SIZE
   Dim tR As RECT
   Dim hTheme As Long
   Dim lR As Long
   hTheme = OpenThemeData(m_hWnd, StrPtr(m_sClass))
   If (hTheme) Then
      lR = GetThemePartSize(hTheme, m_hDC, m_lPartId, m_lStateId, tR, eWidthOptions, tSize)
      If (lR = S_OK) Then
         PartHeight = tSize.cY
      Else
         pFailed "Failed to read part size for class '" & m_sClass & "', partId=" & m_lPartId & ", stateId=" & m_lStateId, lR
      End If
      CloseThemeData hTheme
   Else
      pFailed "No theme data for class '" & m_sClass & "'", Err.LastDllError
   End If
End Property
```

Thanks

I'm trying to port:
http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/libraries/xp_visual_styles/drawing_with_xp_visual_styles/VB6_Theme_Explorer.asp

Comment: You might like to know that in .NET visual styles are applied [a bit easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx). And there are special classes to easily draw controls, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to draw theme parts, I want to extract and save them all as pngs

Comment: [Click just a bit deeper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code in VB6:

```
Public Property Get Width() As Long
   Width = m_lWidth
End Property
Public Property Let Width(ByVal value As Long)
   m_lWidth = value
End Property
```

...is equivalent of this in VB.NET:

```
Public Property Width() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_lWidth
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        m_lWidth = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: @GSerg: yes, of course. Didn't use VB.NET in a long time so I had forgotten that pitfall (and so I went right into it...). Thanks for the correction, answer updated.

Comment: Now
Public Property Width() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_lWidth
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        m_lWidth = Value
    End Set
End Property
can be written as  just "Public Property Width As Integer"

Answer (score 0):

If you are just concerned about the properties, you can check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx#creatingclasses_topic3) to MSDN about VB.NET properties.